# ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: sql

Что нужно подправить?
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 2
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store_simple`.`table1` (
        )
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in the final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: прикрепите запрос

Comment: @David Запрос не выполнялся. Это я Forward Engineer нажал и далее по мастеру пошёл. А вот дальше схема создалась, но запросы не получается делать.